# The word that describes an action to stop two people fighting

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

What is the appropriate verb to complete the gap:

> I saw them fighting and then I ___ them, and finally they could stop.

It doesn't matter whether the context make sense or not. I even made up the sentence above. Anyway, what verb should I put there? I'm sure a few minutes ago I kind of remembered the word, it's a phrasal verb I guess, but I've forgotten when I was distracted. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I **separated** them" is probably the best fit.

> [**separate**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/separate#Verb), verb
> 3. (*transitive*) To cause (things or people) to be separate.
> *If the kids get too noisy, **separate** them for a few minutes.*

If you remove "them" as objects you could say "I **intervened**."

> [**intervene**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intervene#Verb), verb
>
> 1. (*intransitive*) To become involved in a situation, so as to alter or prevent an action.
>    <sup>Synonyms: interfere, step in</sup>
>    *The police had to be called to **intervene** in the fight.*

Meaning 5 of **intervene** is transitive (the example they give is: *The Mediterranean **intervenes** between Europe and Africa*) and you could make a case for using it here, but I don't think that's as idiomatic.

The phrasal verb you remembered, "I **broke** them **up**," would also work very well.

> [**break up**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_up#Verb), verb
> 9. (*transitive, idiomatic*) To stop a fight; to separate people who are fighting.
> *The police came in to **break up** the disturbance.*

Comment: Great! I'd love to use your suggestion. Oh by the way I remember the phrasal verb I've mentioned in the post. Can I use 'break up'? For example, 'I break them up' or 'I break up the fighting.'

Comment: That works too; see my edit.